# Custom joomla module to display category list layout

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

Hello I would like to build a module that display articles of a category (Unfortunately I can't use the native module since these category has other prefix). Something like the native joomla module.

I know how to connect to the table

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
```

the query works :

```
$query = "SELECT title FROM rsc_content WHERE catid=68";
```

Something that might come after (?):

```
$db->setQuery($query);
```

Then I do not know... Any idea?

(i have a code that works to retrieve a single article using joomla code :

```
<?php $db =& JFactory::getDBO(); 
$query = "SELECT introtext FROM rsc_content WHERE id=49 ";
$db->setQuery($query);
$text= $db->loadResult();
echo $text;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First get from database what you need:

```
<?php 
$db =& JFactory::getDBO(); 
$db->setQuery("SELECT title FROM rsc_content WHERE catid=68");
$list= $db->loadResultArray();
```

Then traverse the result list and display contents:

```
foreach($list as $title) {
  echo $title . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Thanks WooDzu ! And how could I get them with a clickable link? (I ll give a try to see how it looks like)

Comment: It depends if you're using SEF or not

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Ok i guess i should manage to make it in SEF. Thanks I did not know about that link... Well your code give me a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in` are you sure about your <br />?

Comment: I'm using the SEF URL. Here is the code, something wrong somewhere ... `    <?php 
$db =& JFactory::getDBO(); 
$db->setQuery("SELECT title FROM rsc_content WHERE catid=68");
$list= $db->loadResultArray();
foreach($list as $title) {
  echo $title . "<br />";
}
    `